# Elasticsearch nodes not participating in indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

*Background*

With our Elasticsearch nodes, I've noticed very high CPU usage per I/O throughput when indexing documents (queries seem to be ok). I was able to increase throughput via vertical scaling (adding more CPUs to the servers) but I wanted to see what kind of increase I would get by horizontal scaling (doubling the number of nodes from 2 to 4).

*Problem*

I expected to see increased throughput with the expanded cluster size but the performance was actually a little worse. I also noticed that half of the nodes reported very little I/O and CPU usage.

*Research*

I saw that the primary shard distribution was wonky so I shuffled some of them around using the re-route API. This didn't really have any effect other than to change which two nodes were being used.

The _search_shards API indicates that all nodes and shards should participate.

*Question*

I'm not sure why only two nodes are participating in indexing. Once a document has been indexed, is there a way to see which shard it resides in? Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

*Setup*

- Servers: 2 CPU, 10g JVM, 18G RAM, 500G SSD
- Index: 8 shards, 1 replica
- Routing Key: _id
- Total Document Count: 4.1M
- Index Document Count: 50k
- Avg Document Size: 14.6K
- Max Document Size: 32.4M

*Stats*

[image: OS Metrics]

[image: JVM Metrics]

[image: I/O Metrics]

*Shards*

```
files-v2           4 r STARTED  664644   8.4gb 10.240.219.136 es-qa-03
files-v2           4 p STARTED  664644   8.4gb 10.240.211.15  es-qa-01
files-v2           7 r STARTED  854807  10.5gb 10.240.53.190  es-qa-04
files-v2           7 p STARTED  854807  10.2gb 10.240.147.89  es-qa-02
files-v2           0 r STARTED  147515 711.4mb 10.240.53.190  es-qa-04
files-v2           0 p STARTED  147515 711.4mb 10.240.211.15  es-qa-01
files-v2           3 r STARTED  347552   1.2gb 10.240.53.190  es-qa-04
files-v2           3 p STARTED  347552   1.2gb 10.240.147.89  es-qa-02
files-v2           1 p STARTED  649461   3.5gb 10.240.219.136 es-qa-03
files-v2           1 r STARTED  649461   3.5gb 10.240.147.89  es-qa-02
files-v2           5 r STARTED  488581   3.6gb 10.240.219.136 es-qa-03
files-v2           5 p STARTED  488581   3.6gb 10.240.211.15  es-qa-01
files-v2           6 r STARTED  186067 916.8mb 10.240.147.89  es-qa-02
files-v2           6 p STARTED  186067 916.8mb 10.240.211.15  es-qa-01
files-v2           2 r STARTED  765970   7.8gb 10.240.53.190  es-qa-04
files-v2           2 p STARTED  765970   7.8gb 10.240.219.136 es-qa-03
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that JVM + Elastic configurations are same on all nodes.
2. For testing purpose - try to make all nodes to hold all data (in your case set number of replicas to 3).
3. About document-shard relation:
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html

Comment: Yeah, I read the sharding/routing formula. Without the hashing algorithm, we can't derive the actual shard though. If I get some time, I'll dig through their source to see if I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think I found it. I'm using Spring Data's Elasticsearch repository. Inside their save(doc) method, there's a call to refresh:

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    Assert.notNull(entity, "Cannot save 'null' entity.");
    elasticsearchOperations.index(createIndexQuery(entity));
    elasticsearchOperations.refresh(entityInformation.getIndexName(), true);
    return entity;
}
```

I bypassed this by invoking the API without Spring's abstraction and the CPU usage for all nodes was much, much better. I'm still not quite clear why a refresh would have effect on 2 nodes (instead of 1 or all) but the issue appears to be resolved.